# “Il y a” in the "futur proche"

Tags: pronoms, questions, futur-proche

Explain, how to convert “il y a” to future immediate?

For example "Sur la table  il y a un livre". "Sur la table il y va a un livre"?

Explain also how to build a question in the futur immediate? For instance, "Qu'y a-t-il dans le mur?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may seem more complicated but it works the same as with any other combination of a verb and a pronoun:

> Je le pense. Je vais le penser.
> Il y a. Il va y avoir.
>
> Que lui offres-tu ? Que vas-tu lui offrir ?
> Qu'y a-t-il ? Que va-t-il y avoir ?

The basic construction is *aller* + infinitive. Object pronouns go before the verb in the infinitive, which is the verb they complement. Subject pronouns in the case of questions are always attached to the conjugated part.

Answer (score 0):

Le terme utilisé en français est « futur proche » et non « futur immédiat ».

La construction consiste à conjuguer le verbe « aller » au présent et à faire suivre par l'infinitif du verb qui est utilisé pour l'action.

Dans le cas de l'idiomatisme « il y a » il faut savoir que le pronom « y » fait partie de l'infinitif; donc on a la transposition suivante;

- Sur la table il va y avoir un livre.

Dans le cas des questions c'est comme d'habitude : inversion.

- Va-t-il y avoir un livre sur la table?
- Que va-t-il y avoir dans le mur?